# Using GregorianCalendar as keys in a HashMap... how do I access the keys?

Tags: java, hashmap, key, gregorian-calendar

I have this HashMap and I want to access each key one by one using a for loop. This is what I have done:

```
    HashMap<GregorianCalendar,ArrayList<String>> hash; //this is the HashMap I want to access
    Set<GregorianCalendar> setCalendars = hash.keySet(); //get a Set containing all the keys
    Object[] arrayCalendars = setCalendars.toArray(); //get an "Array" containing all the keys
    GregorianCalendar calendar;

    for(j = 0; j <= hash.size(); j++){
        calendar = arrayCalendars[j]; //this is the line I'm having trouble with
    }
```

arrayCalendars[j] returns an element of type Object[] but I want it to return a type GregorianCalendar so I can access the month and day variables. Is there a way I could do this?

Comment: `toArray(T[])` returns an array of the correct type. You're the one making it an array of `Object` by using the one that returns Objects http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray(T[])

Comment: Why not just iterate over the `Set` in an enhanced `for` loop?

Comment: I am new to Java of course and my knowledge of the Java API is limited. Solved the problem by using a for each loop.

Comment: The idea to use the bulky GregorianCalendar-objects as keys in a hash map is terrible, performancewise. And compareTo() is not even consistent with equals(), so a sorted iteration is not well supported, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use generic version of `toArray`, which will return `GregorianCalendar[]` array:

```
GregorianCalendar[] arrayCalendars = setCalendars.toArray(new GregorianCalendar[setCalendars.size()]);
```

BTW, you should really drop the idea of using `GregorianCalendar` as key in your map, as it's a mutable class. You should not use mutable type as key in a map.

Comment: this is redundant, the toArray should just have `new GregorianCalendar[0]`

Comment: @rpg711 It's not redundant. Passing 0 length array will actually create a new array right away inside that method. My approach avoids an extra array creation.

Answer (score 0):

You had it (but then you lost it), all you need is this -

```
HashMap<GregorianCalendar,ArrayList<String>> hash; //this is the HashMap I want to access

for (GregorianCalendar calendar : hash.keySet()) {
  // calendar = arrayCalendars[j]; //this is the line I'm having trouble with
      ArrayList<String> al = hash.get(calendar);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try using cast.

```
calendar = (GregorianCalendar) arrayCalendars[j];
```